# TS 2769 with Typescript Vue emit

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, vuejs3

### Update

| ⚠️ Warning |
| --- |
| The checkbox emit doesn't work as the attribute and handler should use `checked` and not `value`, and the event is `@change` not `@input` |

With [@boussadjra-brahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172857/boussadjra-brahim)'s comment I have modified my code. This seems a reasonable way of handling different input types.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

defineProps<{ first: string; last: string, check: boolean }>();

type StringEventType = "update:first" | "update:last"
type BooleanEventType = "update:check"

const emit = defineEmits<{
    (e: StringEventType, value: string): void;
    (e: BooleanEventType, value: boolean): void;
}>();

interface ValueElement extends HTMLElement { value: string; }

const stringValueHandler = <T extends ValueElement>(eventType: StringEventType) =>
        (event: Event) => emit(eventType, (event.target as T).value);

const booleanValueHandler = <T extends ValueElement>(eventType: BooleanEventType) =>
        (event: Event) => emit(eventType, !!(event.target as T).value);

const firstHandler = stringValueHandler<HTMLInputElement>("update:first");
const lastHandler = stringValueHandler<HTMLInputElement>("update:last");
const checkHandler = booleanValueHandler<HTMLInputElement>("update:check");
</script>

<template>
    <form @submit.prevent>
        <label for="first">First Name </label>
        <input id="first" placeholder="Type here" :value="first" @input="firstHandler" />
        <label for="last">Last Name </label>
        <input id="last" placeholder="Type here" :value="last" @input="lastHandler" />
        <label for="confirm">Please confirm</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="confirm" :value="check" @input="checkHandler" />
    </form>
</template>
```

### Original Question

I've been working on creating an example component based on [Multiple v-model bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#multiple-v-model-bindings)  with [Typing Component Emits](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-emits)

It's fairly simple, just two `input` elements. However, I can't quite get the typing correct and am not sure if it's me or perhaps Volar?

Worth noting, I'm doing this in Nuxt 3, though I don't think it matters. I am using some Vue 3.3 syntax though.

[image]

The *red squiggly* is a TS 2769 "No overload matches this call"

[image]

I can fix this by using an intersection type instead of a union

```js
type EventType = "update:first" & "update:last"
```

but that just causes `never` errors when I call my `valueHandler`.

### Code Listing

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

defineProps<{ first: string; last: string }>();

const emit = defineEmits<{
    "update:first": [value: string];
    "update:last": [value: string];
}>();

interface ValueElement extends HTMLElement {
    value: string;
}

type EventType = "update:first" | "update:last"

const valueHandler = <T extends ValueElement>(eventType: EventType) =>
        (event: Event) => emit(eventType, (event.target as T).value);

const firstHandler = valueHandler<HTMLInputElement>("update:first");
const lastHandler = valueHandler<HTMLInputElement>("update:last");
</script>

<template>
    <form @submit.prevent>
        <label for="first">First Name </label>
        <input id="first" placeholder="Type here" :value="first" @input="firstHandler" />
        <label for="last">Last Name </label>
        <input id="last" placeholder="Type here" :value="last" @input="lastHandler" />
    </form>
</template>

<style scoped>
form {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

label,
input {
    display: block;
}

label {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try out `type EventType = "update:first" | "update:last"; 
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: EventType, value: string): void
}>();
`

Comment: Thanks @BoussadjraBrahim , the new 3.3+ syntax didn't seem to work but your suggestion does, and I updated my question with some code that handles boolean checkboxes and that looks ok. I was surprised for some reason, having assumed you'd need a separate defineEmits key for each property :)